# CSS Only image slider for Joomla - Creating my own and adding features

Tags: html, css, joomla, slider, inline

I've just recently started working on a company's Joomla page. Because I'm so new at this they will not give me super administrator privileges so I cannot add JS nor add extensions which would solve my issue a lot quicker.

Anyway, I've been requested to make an automatic scrolling banner with controls (play/pause, previous, next).

I've found a couple of CSS only banners but they don't all seem have the same options.

I'm currently using this one:
http://codepen.io/Eliteware/full/BoBgqV/

```
<head> 
<style>
/* Reset */
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

/* Slider */
#slider{
  width:100%;
  height:360px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
@keyframes load{
  from{left:-100%;}
  to{left:0;}
}
.slides{
  width:400%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-animation:slide 30s infinite;
  -moz-animation:slide 30s infinite;
  animation:slide 30s infinite;
}
.slider{
  width:25%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slide img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.slide img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.image{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.image img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

/* Legend */
.legend{
  border:500px solid transparent;
  border-left:800px solid rgba(52, 73, 94, .7);
  border-bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}

/* Contents */
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.content-txt{
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  top:300px;
  -webkit-animation:content-s 7.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation:content-s 7.5s infinite;
  animation:content-s 7.5s infinite;
}
.content-txt h1{
  font-family:Intro;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:30px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
.content-txt h2{
  font-family:Quicksand;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:14px;
  font-style:italic;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:30px;
}

/* Switch */
.switch{
  width:120px;
  height:10px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  z-index:99;
}
.switch > ul{
  list-style:none;
}
.switch > ul > li{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#333;
  margin-right:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.switch ul{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.on{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#14b0d3
  position:relative;
  -webkit-animation:on 30s infinite;
  -moz-animation:on 30s infinite;
  animation:on 30s infinite;
}

/* Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slide{
  0%,100%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  21%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  25%{
    margin-left:-100%;
  }
  46%{
    margin-left:-100%;
  }
  50%{
    margin-left:-200%;
  }
  71%{
    margin-left:-200%;
  }
  75%{
    margin-left:-300%;
  }
  96%{
    margin-left:-300%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide{
  0%,100%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  21%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  25%{
    margin-left:-100%;
  }
  46%{
    margin-left:-100%;
  }
  50%{
    margin-left:-200%;
  }
  71%{
    margin-left:-200%;
  }
  75%{
    margin-left:-300%;
  }
  96%{
    margin-left:-300%;
  }
}
@keyframes slide{
  0%,100%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  21%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  25%{
    margin-left:-100%;
  }
  46%{
    margin-left:-100%;
  }
  50%{
    margin-left:-200%;
  }
  71%{
    margin-left:-200%;
  }
  75%{
    margin-left:-300%;
  }
  96%{
    margin-left:-300%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes content-s{
  0%{left:-420px;}
  10%{left:0px;}
  30%{left:0px;}
  40%{left:0px;}
  50%{left:0px;}
  60%{left:0px;}
  70%{left:0;}
  80%{left:-420px;}
  90%{left:-420px;}
  100%{left:-420px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes content-s{
  0%{left:-420px;}
  10%{left:0px;}
  30%{left:0px;}
  40%{left:0px;}
  50%{left:0px;}
  60%{left:0px;}
  70%{left:0;}
  80%{left:-420px;}
  90%{left:-420px;}
  100%{left:-420px;}
}
@keyframes content-s{
  0%{left:-420px;}
  10%{left:20px;}
  15%{left:0px;}
  30%{left:0px;}
  40%{left:0px;}
  50%{left:0px;}
  60%{left:0px;}
  70%{left:0;}
  80%{left:-420px;}
  90%{left:-420px;}
  100%{left:-420px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes on{
  0%,100%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  21%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  25%{
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  46%{
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  50%{
    margin-left:30px;
  }
  71%{
    margin-left:30px;
  }
  75%{
    margin-left:45px;
  }
  96%{
    margin-left:45px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes on{
  0%,100%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  21%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  25%{
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  46%{
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  50%{
    margin-left:30px;
  }
  71%{
    margin-left:30px;
  }
  75%{
    margin-left:45px;
  }
  96%{
    margin-left:45px;
  }
}

@keyframes on{
  0%,100%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  21%{
    margin-left:0%;
  }
  25%{
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  46%{
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  50%{
    margin-left:30px;
  }
  71%{
    margin-left:30px;
  }
  75%{
    margin-left:45px;
  }
  96%{
    margin-left:45px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="i-contenedor">
<div style="width:1024px;height:auto;max-width:100%;overflow:hidden;border:none;padding:0;margin:0 auto;display:block;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">

<div id="slider">
   <div class="slides">
      <!-- First slide --> 
     <div class="slider">
         <div class="images"> 
            <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60&catid=24&Itemid=101"><img src="images/banner_03080255.png"></a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Second slide --> 
      <div class="slider">
         <div class="images"> 
            <img src="images/banner_03080905.png"> 
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Third slide --> 
<div class="slider">
         <div class="images"> 
            <img src="images/banner_03080924.png"> 
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Fourth slide --> 
<div class="slider">
         <div class="images"> 
            <img src="images/ach_comunicacion_feb_27.jpg"> 
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>

        </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
```

It works perfectly and has automatic reproduction of the slides like I wanted vía keyframes. I managed to change the size to suit my needs.

Now I need to add the controls but I'm stuck because I can barely understand some of the things that are being done with this CSS.

Now, here is another option: http://qnimate.com/creating-a-slider-using-html-and-css-only/. A much simpler code that has a way for me to choose which slide I want. But no automatic reproduction nor a way to pause.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>QNimate Slider</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider-holder">
        <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
        <div class="image-holder">
            <img src="1.jpg" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="2.jpg" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="3.jpg" class="slider-image" />
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
            <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
            <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
 .slider-holder
        {
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .image-holder
        {
            width: 2400px;
            background-color: red;
            height: 400px;
            clear: both;
            position: relative;

            -webkit-transition: left 2s;
            -moz-transition: left 2s;
            -o-transition: left 2s;
            transition: left 2s;
        }

        .slider-image
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: 0px;
        }

        #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -800px;
        }

        #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -1600px;
        }

        .button-holder
        {
            position: relative;
            top: -20px;
        }

        .slider-change
        {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: brown;
        }
```

I mostly want to learn how to join certain elements to create a simple CSS and HTML only image slider because I've been searching forever and I never get exactly what I need.

I know the basic structure and elements of the image slider.

- Slider container
- slide
- image
- Arrows the slide I'm on
- dots that control the slide I'm on
- Pause/play button which pauses or plays the slide I'm on

Comment: Thanks you saved my day ! Igo to Beez template , created css and put the code in homepage to play it.